# Missing iPhoto Comments

Tags: photos.app, photos

When I upload photos from my iPhoto Library on my old MacBook (OS 10.4.11; iPhoto 6.0.6 (3.2.2.)) to Dropbox and download them from Dropbox onto my new MacBook (OS 10.8.5; iPhoto 11, version 9.4.2), I get the photos but not the comments.  The comments on the individual pictures that I entered in iPhoto into the little information box in the lower left-hand corner seem to have been lost in the process.
The same thing happens when I burn them on a CD and copy them from the CD onto my new MacBook. Again, I see the photos but not the comments. (I can see the  comments if I look at the photos on the CD, but not if I copy them from the CD into my iPhotolibrary and look at them there.) 
My questions: (i) How can I make the comments visible?  (ii) Will the comments be visible if I transfer the photos from the old to the new Macbook with a firewire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when you are not using methods that also moves the metadata file with the photos.

For some reason iPhoto decided not to make it simple to move photos arround or move them out of iPhoto hugging.

I recommend a app called [Photoshare](https://sites.google.com/site/phosharedoc/) that allows you to choose and export all data associated with the photos.